# Python Code but can't use the max and min functions

Tags: python

The problem I have is with my output. Like it shows the correct max and min just not the corresponding month to go with it. I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work. I'm new to the Python programming. I have attached my code and sample output. Can someone help me figure this out?

```
'''this code will get rainfall amount for a given month
from the user and calculate the total and find
the largest and smallest rainfall month plus
the average rainfall.'''


#create the variables and list

months = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
total = 0
average = 0
amounts = []

#set up the loop to get user input
#for the rainfall amount of each
#month.
for i in range(len(months)):
    month = int(input("Enter the rainfall for month " + str(months[i])+ ":"))

    while month <=0:
        print("ERROR! Wrong Value! Try Again")
        month = int(input("Enter the rainfall for month " + str(months[i])+ ":"))

    amounts.append(month)

    #calculate the total
    total += month

#calculate the average
average = total / 12

'''calculate the month with the
most and least rainfall'''
large = amounts[0]
small = amounts[0]

for i in range (1,len(amounts)):
    if amounts[i]> large:
        large = amounts[i]  

    if amounts[i] < small:
        small = amounts[i]

print("The total is " + str(total)+ " inches")
print("The average is " + str(average)+ " inches")
print ("The month with the most rain is " + str((large)))
print("The month with the least rain is " + str((small)))
```

sample Output

```
Enter the rainfall for month 1:4
Enter the rainfall for month 2:5
Enter the rainfall for month 3:6
Enter the rainfall for month 4:7
Enter the rainfall for month 5:8
Enter the rainfall for month 6:9
Enter the rainfall for month 7:25
Enter the rainfall for month 8:26
Enter the rainfall for month 9:11
Enter the rainfall for month 10:1
Enter the rainfall for month 11:10
Enter the rainfall for month 12:12
The total is 124 inches
The average is 10.333333333333334 inches
The month with the most rain is 26
The month with the least rain is 1
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are asking? If the code is returning unexpected output, please [edit] the question to say what you expected instead. See the [mcve] help page for details. Also, what is meant by "can't use the max and min functions" – are you *technically* unable to (you get an error) or do some requirements forbid using the functions?

Comment: I was saying my output is correct it just doesn't display the month that goes with the number it's just the number. and my professor said don't use the max and min functions.

Answer (score 0):

`large` and `small` contain the minimum and maximum rainfalls, not the month that they occurred.

You can use another pair of variables to hold the month numbers.

```
large_month = 0
large = amounts[0]
small_month = 0
small = amounts[0]

for i in range(1, len(amounts)):
    if amounts[i]> large:
        large = amounts[i]
        large_month = i

    if amounts[i] < small:
        small = amounts[i]
        small_month = i

print("The total is " + str(total)+ " inches")
print("The average is " + str(average)+ " inches")
print ("The month with the most rain is " + str(large_month+1))
print("The month with the least rain is " + str(small_month+1))
```